# What exactly is the difference between client and client.Client in a Django TestCase?

Tags: django, testing

My understanding from reading the docs runs something like this:

1. client is a subclass of TestCase. When we run `manage.py test`, an instance of our SimpleTest class (which inherits from TestCase) is created for each method that starts 'test_'. This is `self`.
2. Client is a subclass of client. We can create new Client instances and sometimes it's helpful to do so.
3. Yet somehow, when we type `self.client`, what we are referring to is a particular Client that was instantiated when the TestCase was created, and **not** the client class one layer below TestCase.

Is this correct? If so, how is this the case - something to do with Superclasses?

Comment: self.client **is not** the same as just client - the first one is a property, the second is a variable. I believe giving code example would help us understand your question, and trying this code yourself would help you understand the difference.

Comment: Thanks for the help. This is clearer to me now - Client is descended not from TestCase but from test, and as you say, self.client is simply a property pointing at this Client. That was a helpful distinction, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i'm understanding both your question and the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/#django.test.TestCase.client) correctly.  The `client` property is provided as a convenience it makes sense that each test has access to a  `from django.test.client import Client` Client instance.

Your first question:

1. client is a subclass of TestCase. When we run manage.py test, an instance of our SimpleTest class (which inherits from TestCase) is created for each method that starts 'test_'. This is self.

from the [source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/test/client.py#L327) It doesn't look like Client is a subclass of TestCase at all.

```
class Client(RequestFactory):
    """
    A class that can act as a client for testing purposes.
```

From the source I don't see where? the Client class is being instantiated and attached to TestCase instance but it is somewhere.

Django is completely open source so given some free time it is easy to track down how things and where things are happening.  https://github.com/django/django  Following the import paths and grepping around can find all answers

Comment: Aha - you're absolutely right! I was sure I'd read "self.client.Client" somewhere, but this morning I couldn't find it anywhere - how silly! As you say, Client is descended from django.test, not TestCase, and the self.client in a test points naturally enough to that instance without any conflicts.

Comment: Thanks also for the link to the actual source on github. That's very helpful, and I'm sure will answer many of my questions in future.